# How do you fetch users posts with accurate sorting order, using mongo db, in a facebook like application

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am building a social media application similar to facebook with mongodb, I will like the users post feeds to be sorted by

1. if user is following the author of the post
2. how popular the post is, for example, the number of likes and the number of comments
3. the location of the user, (if it is same with the author of the post)
4. sort by the value of (count of "like reaction" for last 6 months - count of value of "sad   reaction" for last 6 months)
5. lastly the time at which the post was created

here is the schema of the database

```js
user: {
  _id: mongoId
  username: string
  location_id: ref location _id
}

post: {
  _id: mongoId
  content: string
  author: ref user _id
}

comment: {
  _id: mongoId
  content: string
  post: ref post _id
  author: ref user _id
}

reaction: {
  _id: mongoId
  type: enum['like', 'love', 'sad']
  post: ref post _id
  author: ref user _id
}

follow: {
  _id: mongoId
  follower: ref user _id of the one who is following another
  following: ref user _id of the one who is being followed another
}

location: {
  _id: mongoId
  country: string
}
```

i will like a mongo query that will fetch this posts in the order of the sort i mentioned, i will really appreciate any help at all, even though not all the sort values can be accomplished, just mention which ones can and how i can achieve that

I have tried using the $sort, $sortByCount, $group $sum and some other aggregate methods, but i am not getting the right order

I am expecting to see the posts fetched in desending  order

Comment: you are treating mongoDB as a relational database, in a Document database, you would have comments inside the posts, together with user for example, we don't split things apart like in a relational database, nevertheless, you can use `aggregate` and use `$lookup` to join collections, but will be slow if you have a lot or documents